# Covariate in Repeated Measures

Tags: repeated-measures, predictor

I'm using repeated measures ANOVA with one independent within-subject variable and six dependent variables.

I want to control the order of the intervention (categorical variable with two levels: 1,2). In order to do that, do I just need to put the order variable in the "covariate" box? Do I need to transform the variable into dummy variable (0,1 instead of 1,2)

Also, I wanted to make sure about the interpretation of the data- the results reflect the effect of the within-subject variable, **without** the effect of order?

Comment: Are you operating within some statistical package? You mention putting something in a covariate box; are you using SPSS?

Comment: Hi. I'm using the General Linear Model - Repeated Measures option using spss.